# How the position has been changed from relative to fixed dynamically/programmatically in websites like Netflix, w3schools etc.?

Tags: html, css, sass, netflix

I observed in the Netflix home page - while scrolling the header container (please see following image: [netflix home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNq9d.png) ) style will automatically change from relative position to fixed position so that it always sticks at the top. I see this similar behavior in many websites: espncrinfo or https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp . I am interested in knowing how these websites are doing this - just by looking at chrome developer tools didnt give me much details.

**Question:**

is it as simple as just listening to scroll event (javascript) and updating the style, or can it be done by **just using CSS without listening to scroll events**? just curious as i am ok with css basics - but wondering if i am missing any advanced techniques like transform or translate here?

Before scroll:
html:

```
<div class="pinning-header-container" style="top: 0px; position: relative; background: transparent;">
</div>
```

css:

```
element.style {
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
```

After scroll:

```
element.style {
    top: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    background: rgb(20, 20, 20);
}
```

Comment: Hope this example is helpful https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header

Comment: nice example @Ramesh - from example its done with javascript by listenting scroll event and checking for offset in Y-axis - am looking for just css way if possible. May be by just using css is not possible...

Comment: No brother. Unfortunately you can't do this only using css. Because css doesn't have a feature as you expect. You need to handle this with javascript

Answer (score 0):

> is it as simple as just listening to scroll event (javascript) and updating the style

Traditionally it was done like this and until recently, there was no other way.

> can it be done by just using CSS without listening to scroll events?

Yes, in most recent browsers you can just use [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).
It has [decent browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) and there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/stickybits).